# Can I use adsense in TWA App or do I need to use admob

Tags: android, admob, apk, adsense, twa

I have a twa android app. Can I use the same adsense in the website or do I need to change it to admob?

Comment: Hello any reply appreciated

Comment: did you get an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Just if anyone is here in 2023: You don't need AdMob for TWA. AdSense it's okay.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33638346)

Comment: can you provide any citation for google saying it is allowed please?